# email library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am using $this->load->library('email'); library in codeigniter , it working fine, while am sending the email by using this library mail also send with the HTML code , there is any configuration need to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'HTML';
```

From the userguide:  Type of mail. If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete web page. Make sure you don't have any relative links or relative image paths otherwise they will not work.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html